# Almacenar variables output de un bucle en Python

Tags: python, array, lista, variables, bucles

Necesitaría saber cómo almacenar las variables output de un bucle (por ejemplo, en columnas de excel (x,n) o para plotear). He probado con .append, creando una lista, pero tan sólo se puede con una variable. Pongo un ejemplo sencillo de lo que pretendo hacer: en este caso, sería almacenar (x,n) y hacer un plot después con la lista de valores output del bucle.

```
lst=[]
for y in [0,8] : 
    for z in [0,1,2,3] :
        x=y+z
        n=x+2
        lst.append(x)

print (lst)
plt.plot(lst, color='blue')  
plt.figure(1)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('PID ≡ RPM')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes almacenarlos en una lista de tuplas: `List[Tuple[int, int]]`:

```
lst = []
for y in [0,8]: 
    for z in [0,1,2,3]:
        x=y+z
        n=x+2
        lst.append((x,n))
```

Y accedes dentro de las tuplas como un array más:

```
print(lst)
print(lst[0])
print(lst[1])
print(lst[0][0])
print(lst[0][1])
```

O podrías meterlos en una lista de *namedtuples* como una lista de vectores: `List[Vector[int, int]]`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Vector = namedtuple("Vector", field_names=["x", "y"])

lst = []
for y in [0,8]: 
    for z in [0,1,2,3]:
        x=y+z
        n=x+2
        lst.append(Vector(x, n))

print(lst)
print(lst[0].x)
print(lst[0].y)
print(lst[1])
```

Y como resultado te da:

```
[Vector(x=0, y=2), Vector(x=1, y=3), Vector(x=2, y=4), Vector(x=3, y=5), Vector(x=8, y=10), Vector(x=9, y=11), Vector(x=10, y=12), Vector(x=11, y=13)]
0
2
Vector(x=1, y=3)
```